# Rails dropdown with "Others" option to be stored in same field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form like this

```
<% simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :organization_name, ["Apple", "Google", "Microsoft", "Others"] %>    
  <div id="custom_org_id hide">
    <%= f.input :organization_name, label: "Others" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

javascript

```
$('#user_organization_name').change(function() {
  $('#custom_org_id').removeClass('hide');
});
```

User is shown a dropdown which contains the organization names which can be selected and submitted. There is an "others" option which when clicked opens an input field and user can type into it.
The problem here is if the user selects "others" option and enters some value into it, which value gets stored in database? because if you observe above, in the dropdown and the input field the attribute name is same which is

```
:organization_name
```

and I dont want a seperate column for others.
How can we achieve this

Comment: When end user select to have the value form the input box then in that sitaution you can make the select box disable, It will prevent to submit it.

Comment: Yeah but I guess when the user selects "Others" from the dropdown that stays as the input for the field.. though it is disabled and gets submitted when user submits.. I dont know whether this is correct.. Iam guessing.. If this is not corrct then what u said works..

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
<% simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
<div id="custom_org_id_select_menu">
    <%= f.select :organization_name, ["Apple", "Google", "Microsoft", "Others"] %>    
 </div>  

  <div id="custom_org_id hide">
    <%= f.input :organization_name, label: "Others" %>
  </div>
<% end %>


$( "#user_organization_name" ).keypress(function() {
    $('#custom_org_id_select_menu').removeClass();
});
```

Once you start typing in the "other" in put field then your drop down disappears. If you want the option of making it re-appear then simply build it again using jquery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... even though the drop down disappears, the value in the drop down is still "Others". So when the user selects "Other" from the drop down and enter some value in the input field which value gets stored.. either 1) "Other" from the dropdown or 2) Entered value in the input field because both are submitted for the same attribute(:organization_name)

Comment: @AdityaY it should be the value that is entered in the input field..........but you'll have to check to be sure. my understanding is that the selection menu will have been basically "deleted" from the form, leaving only the correct option left. But what if the user does not choose "others"? I am not sure what value will be submitted.........I would suggest then using a hidden field and then checking whether that field has a value.